# How to change the background color of notification on Android 12

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-12

I would like to make the notification look a different color completely, I am using local notifications so I would like to be able to do this with `NotificationCompat.Builder` if possible.

Here's an example of what I would like the notification to look like:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Using notification builder methods

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
     .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primaryColor))
     .setColorized(true)
     .....
     .build()
```

Comment: Only this way It will not work. From docs: 
This should only be used for high priority ongoing tasks like navigation, an ongoing call, or other similarly high-priority events for the user.
For most styles, the coloring will only be applied if the notification is for a foreground service notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that your notification is a notification from the service, then the methods will work **setColorized**, **setColor**

```
.setFlag(Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE, true)
.setColorized(true)
.setColor(Color.BLUE)
```